# Why a VPN slows down LAN access?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, debian, performance, openvpn

We have an access server providing VPN to some of our clients and the workforce with laptops. They usually connect from outside of the office, and everything works fine. However, for simplicity and also security, when someone connects from within the office, VPN is also used on the LAN. That works fine as well, except that the speed on the LAN connection is very slow, compared to 1Gbps of the LAN. `scp` yields 150kB/s using VPN and full speed (which varies as the desktop computers take a lot of bandwidth themselves, but is about 20 times faster) if I manually connect surpassing VPN. So,

- Question 1: What could be the cause of it?
- Question 2: How can I improve it? (people are really complaining)
- Question 3: If the answer to the above two questions is unknown, how can I further diagnose it?

The OpenVPN configs are as follows:

Server:

```
dev tun
ifconfig 10.0.2.1 10.0.2.2
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key
proto tcp-server
port 1194
cipher DES-EDE-CBC
daemon
verb 4
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
keepalive 10 900
comp-lzo
```

Client:

```
remote 10.0.1.3
secret /home/jkowalski/openvpn.key
dev tun
proto tcp-client
port 1194
cipher DES-EDE-CBC
ifconfig 10.0.2.2 10.0.2.1
script-security 2
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

I have tried so far:
Changing the cipher, port, compression setting. Disabling encryption altogether. No errors in the server log, although some machines take a long time to connect.
The server machine is a Debian 7.8 32 bit. Client machines are Windows 7/8.1 64 bit, XP 32 bit and Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: I never found out what the original problem was. The solution was to upgrade to a 64-bit Debian 9. Now everything works fine. I also switched to UDP and it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with `when someone connects from within the office VPN is also used on the LAN`?

Comment: Sounds like the answer is "because you did set it up wrong". WIthin a LAN - properly set up - VPN (though not needed) should not really result in a large hit. That said, a VPN endpoint capable of handling multiple gigabit traffic is likely not what you have...  Bad setup. Which is why MS created DirectAccess as technology of automatically managed transparent VPN's... so users do not have to learn not to open a VPN in the company.

Comment: @fvu I've added the missing comma :)

Comment: @TomTom Yeah... I guess you are right. Unfortunately I have little influence on what I get handed. I inherited the aforementioned architecture with little room for radical change. In fact the bottom line is: you fix it mister, or we will have someone else do it. I am sure an experienced person like you understands. Besides, the rest of the network runs like a top so there is absolutely no need for any radical change.

Comment: Well, then start checking your OpenVPN server. Providing a multi gigabit throughput is likely overstressing it.

Comment: @TomTom naaaa... It's a 6 core Athlon... the load oscillates around 3. In fact it was one of the first things I checked. It must be something else. I was thinking about some problems with the PHY + the inability of OpenVPN to handle time-outs properly... something like that...

Comment: I believe OpenVPN at least had a limitation in being single threaded, that is it could run on a single core at a time regardless of the number of cores available. I don't know the latest development, but you may wish to look into that.

Comment: I did tests when no one else was logged in and I looked at the openvpn daemon specifically to see the load it generated. It used like 2% of the CPU.

Comment: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Gigabit_Networks_Linux ??

Comment: Did you already try switching proto to udp?

Comment: Agreed with @fvu. Don't use TCP for VPN tunnels unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @fvu Not yet. Actually this is one thing that I know I should try but haven't so far. I will, thx.

Comment: @KonradGajewski if you ever figure this out, please add the solution you found, thank you :)

Comment: Old post, but I have the same issue but on Windows Server 2019. When connected to vpn Lan performances goes from 90MB/s to 10MB/s during a file transfer. No route is changed, traffic goes the same way, etc. but something on OpenVPN client happens that limit the traffic. some parameter set, dont know. CPU usage is the same. When I disconnect from VPN automatically the file transfer goes back to 90MB/s